Two sessions in the same client, only one of them receiving messages from a certain group
I have joined a certain telegram channel with two different telegram accounts. I run the below code to start both sessions using pyrogram and print the received message. But I noticed that when a message was received on the telegram channel only one of them printed and the other didn't. However when I tested using my own test telegram channel I couldn't repro the issue, i.e., both the sessions printed the message on the test channel. I'm at a loss why the problem happens with the other channel. Both the numbers  are subscribed to the channel, and on the phone app the message is seen on both the phones. What would possibly cause this most bizarre behavior?
#!/usr/bin/python3

from pyrogram import Client, filters, idle
from pyrogram.handlers import MessageHandler
import config
from pytz import timezone
from datetime import datetime
import requests
import asyncio

CHANNEL_ID = -1000123456789

def india_number_handler(client, message):
    message_handler('india_number', message)
    
def uk_number_handler(client, message):
    message_handler('uk_number', message) 
    
def message_handler(session_name, message):
    if message.sender_chat is not None and message.sender_chat.id == CHANNEL_ID and message.text is not None:
        print(datetime.now().strftime('%d-%m-%Y-%H:%M:%S-%f') + ': ' + session_name + ' received channel message: ' + message.text, flush = True
    
async def main():
    app_india = Client("india_number", api_id=config.getEnv("api_id"), api_hash=config.getEnv("api_hash"))
    app_uk = Client("uk_number", api_id=config.getEnv("api_id"), api_hash=config.getEnv("api_hash"))
    app_india.add_handler(MessageHandler(india_number_handler))
    app_uk.add_handler(MessageHandler(uk_number_handler))    
    await app_india.start()
    await app_uk.start()
    await idle()
    await app.stop()
    await app_uk.stop()
         
asyncio.run(main())

Update 1: I was eventually able to repro the issue with my test channel, only the india session printed and nothing got printed from the uk session. I noticed something curious - when I swapped the order of start() statements so that app_uk.start() occurs first, then the uk session started printing and the india session went silent. This suggests something wrong is happening relating to thread blocking, although it is confusing why the inconsistent behavior of both sessions successfully receiving events earlier on my test channel.
Update 2: I modified my code to handle only 1 session and ran two instances of the script from different terminals, one for each telegram account, but even now only one of them is receiving the message, so this is not an issue with any incorrect async usage. Also this setup works  on my test channel but only not on the same channel where it didn't work before. This is very frustrating.

Some potential causes can be rate limiting, session interference, order of execution, API restricitions or maybe concurrency issues. I suggest you try to run each session in a separate script and see if it helps.

Sending messages are you successful with both accounts?
If not, what is the error written to you?

@Lanre, if you see my update 2 above, that is exactly what I already tried but it still didn't work.
